# Alternating Grouped Rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have code that does alternating rows and works, but I need to figure out a way to group the alternating rows using JS. I'm trying to use "company" (for example) as the identifier.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[VIEW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7DXl.jpg)

I've got this code for alternating rows (below), but am not able to figure out (or find) any solution to group the rows by an identified row.

All help is so appreciated!

```
var tblrows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tblrows.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0) tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fffff';
    else tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    const tblrows = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("td"));

    const tblrows_values = tblrows.map((tblrow) => {
      return tblrow.textContent;
    });

    tblrows_values.forEach((tblrow_value, index) => {
      const tr = tblrows[index].parentNode;

      if (parseInt(tblrow_value) % 2 === 0) {
        tr.style.backgroundColor = index % 2 === 0 ? "white" : "red";
      } else {
        tr.style.backgroundColor = index % 2 === 0 ? "red" : "white";
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is already sorted by the company name, you only need to keep track of the previous company, and if it's different that's when you change what you change the background color to.

```js
const tblrows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');

let previousCompany = "";
const colors = ['red', '#ffffff'];
let color;

for (const row of tblrows) {
  if (row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText !== previousCompany) {
    previousCompany = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText;
    color = colors[(colors.indexOf(color) + 1) % colors.length];
  }
  row.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Country One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Michael Townley</td>
      <td>Country One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Jane Smith</td>
      <td>Country One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Robert Johnson</td>
      <td>Country Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Emily Davis</td>
      <td>Country Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Michael Wilson</td>
      <td>Country Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Sarah Brown</td>
      <td>Country Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>David Lee</td>
      <td>Country Seven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Amy Johnson</td>
      <td>Country Four</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```